# This code is simple file upload.How to upload multi files with using this way.thx

Tags: c#

```
    public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file", ex.Message);
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String token = args[0];

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("token", token);
        nvc.Add("name", "mms-deneme");
        nvc.Add("frame_count", "1");
        nvc.Add("frame_1_text", "1. resim text");
        nvc.Add("frame_1_duration", "15");
        HttpUploadFile("https://api.turkcell.hedeflimesaj.com/mms.json",
             @"C:\test\test.jpg", "frame_1_visual", "image/jpeg", nvc);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html) I wrote on this subject.

---

UPDATE:

Posting the source code as the link didn't work for the OP:

Have you ever been in a situation where you needed to upload multiple files to a remote host and pass additional parameters in the request? Unfortunately there's nothing in the BCL that allows us to achieve this out of the box.

We have the [UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) method but it is restricted to a single file and doesn't allow us to pass any additional parameters. So let's go ahead and write such method. The important part is that this method must comply with [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) so that the remote web server can successfully parse the information.

First we define a model representing a single file to be uploaded:

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public UploadFile()
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a sample UploadFiles method implementation:

```
public byte[] UploadFiles(string address, IEnumerable<UploadFile> files, NameValueCollection values)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    boundary = "--" + boundary;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Write the values
        foreach (string name in values.Keys)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"{1}{1}", name, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values[name] + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // Write the files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}", file.Name, file.Filename, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Type: {0}{1}{1}", file.ContentType, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        var boundaryBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "--");
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBuffer, 0, boundaryBuffer.Length);
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And here's a sample usage:

```
using (var stream1 = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream2 = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream3 = File.Open("test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    var files = new[] 
    {
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.txt",
            ContentType = "text/plain",
            Stream = stream1
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.xml",
            ContentType = "text/xml",
            Stream = stream2
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.pdf",
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            Stream = stream3
        }
    };

    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
        { "key3", "value3" },
    };

    byte[] result = UploadFiles("http://localhost:1234/upload", files, values);
}
```

In this example we are uploading 3 values and 3 files to the remote host.

Comment: @user714869, I've included the source code from the blog post. Please see my update.

Comment: Wouldn't it make better use of the server and network to use System.WebClient.UploadFileAsync(...) several times?

Comment: @Adrian, you will be making multiple requests in this case. My code could be easily adapted to use the async versions of the `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse`.